# Why am I unable to start a connection using my operator's port in RapidMiner?

Tags: excel, import, operators, port, rapidminer

I'm unable to move or open the operators in my process view in RapidMiner. It has this numbers on top which does not happen normally. Can someone please tell me what to do?
I have attached an image for your reference

I'm trying to connect the "readExcel" operator to the results port but I'm unable to move the operator or start a connection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely toggled the "execution order" overlay: [image: RapidMiner workflow with toggled execution order overlay.]

This overlay lets you change the execution order for operators that have no implicit ordering (one must follow the other because of a direct connection) but are "parallel". This is helpful if you calculate a value in one branch of the workflow and need that in another branch.

Advise: If the results are depending on the execution order, try to make it implicit by adding direct connections. Otherwise always check the execution order before saving, it may change when adding new operators or connections.